# How to Apply a GCC Patch

Tags: gcc, patch, gcc4

I'm trying to apply [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=15987) patch to GCC on MinGW to get it [to compile GDC 2](https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/wiki/MinGWCompile), but I don't know how. (I'm still new to the internals of GCC, and even to *nix tools in general.) I know there's the `patch` command but I can't figure out how to use it, and I don't even know if I have enough information for this.

How do I apply the patch for GCC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default GNU Patch can be used by feeding a patch file to it from `stdin` (console input), e.g.:

```
patch < file.patch
```

There are many switches and options `patch` can use, the functionality is described here:

http://www.rtr.com/winpak/Documentation/patch.htm

http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_mono/diff.html#Invoking%20patch

`patch` and `diff` work hand in hand. A small demonstration is found on [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29#Usage_examples).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the patch manual pages. Just type `man patch` in a terminal window... typically i think you want to do a `patch -p0 -i your_file.diff`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is MinGW (on Windows), and there's no `man` command; I looked at `patch --help` but I didn't figure out how to use it. (By the way, do I need a `patch` file or a `diff` file, or both? I only have the former.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Sorry probably the .diff extension mislead you :). The patch file is the output of the diff command. It's a text file. The patch command will apply the patch file to your local files. Maybe you can just do `patch < patch_file_name` too... I'm not sure since I can't really test it out here.

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't work. I feel like I'm missing an important file (or files)...

Comment: @Mehrdad OK. Sorry I really don't know MinGW. As you might imagine, it's hard to tell from my end if you're missing anything :(.