# Source code merging

Tags: svn, gcc, version

I have a patch to gcc-4.3.1. But i need upgrade to gcc-4.5.0 with keeping functionality added with the patch. Please explain me how i can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189085/how-to-apply-a-gcc-patch

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a local copy of the gcc sources in your svn? In this case, merge your changes from your local gcc-4.3.1 copy into your local gcc-4.5.0 copy. There's a section in the svn book about vendor branches, that deals with this problem: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html

Another option is to use svn diff to create patch files which you apply to your checked out gcc-4.5.0 sources.

Comment: ok. how to know what revision is for 4.3.1 and for 4.5.0?  it will look like:  svn co trunk/gcc gcc43 -r431; svn co trunk/gcc gcc45 -r450; patch gcc43 < p.diff; right? and what further?

Comment: no, more like
cd your_gcc_431_sources;
svn diff > my_changes.patch;
cd;
svn co gcc45;
cd gcc45;
patch -p 0 < ../gcc431/my_changes.patch;

Comment: how to know what revision is for 4.3.1 and for 4.5.0?